# Is it possible to make a non-child element be affected by overflow hidden? If not, what are some work arounds?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create an overlay with a white sidebar and header that begin changing color to black when an expander starts filling the screen. The expander fills the screen from the center so parts of the header and sidebar should be black while the parts not covered by the expander should be white.

So far, I have tried positioning a duplicate header/sidebar with the desired properties inside of the expander div but the scaling and positioning ended up being a nightmare as I used JS to apply a transform property on the expander, resulting in the nested elements expanding as well.

The current best approach that I came up with is to somehow use overflow hidden and position the sidebar and header outside of the expander but I'm now running into the problem of the overflow not affecting the duplicate sidebar/header because they're not children of the expander.

Is there a way around this or is my architecture just no good?

Edit: added some code

Expander is inside a container called scroll2. Scroll2 is just the second scroll component of the website.

```
<div id="scroll2">
            <div id="scroll2Box" />
            <div id="expander" />
            <div id="scroll2BoxImages" />
</div>
```

Expander CSS

```
#expander {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: black;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: scale(0);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Expander's transform style changes based on the user's scroll position.

```
document.getElementById('expander').style.transform = 'scale(' + String(heightRatio) + ')'
```

My header and sidebar components are outside of the scroll entirely and are placed in my router logic area.

```
<Router>
    <Sidebar yPosition={y} direction={direction}/>
    <Header yPosition={y}/>
    <div id="mainContent">
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
            <Route path="/contact" component={ContactPage} />
            <Route path="/products" component={ProductsPage} />
       </Switch>
    </div>
    {/* <Footer /> not complete yet */}
</Router>
```

Comment: Hello James. Please drop some code alongside your question. It makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Sorry just added!

Comment: Hi, I'm not clear what color in the header and sidebar should start to change when the expander expands over (?under?) them. I assume they are not just to be covered by the black expander but are to somehow change their own coloring. Is it their background, their text color,  a combination?...

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying that earlier. The header is originally white with black text/links and once the expander starts going over the header, I'd like it to partly change to a black background and white text/links so it fits the theme of all black for the third part of the page. I've thought about using js to partially change the colors of the text/links of the header but I can't find any simple solutions.